# Standard cauchy distribution integration of second moment

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am looking at the below solution from a book regarding the standard Cauchy distribution. As I understand it, a random variable $X$ that is Cauchy distributed is supported in $(-\infty, +\infty)$. So if you integrate $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, don't you obtain infinity? Why does it say here that it tends to 1?

[image]

Comment: A sufficient condition to show the second moment is infinite is the fact that $x^2/(1+x^2)$  does not approach zero in the limit $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I think it means $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\to 1$ as $x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: @StevenClark Ah, that would make sense. The second moment is the integral of that expression, right? Or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: @roulette01 that's right.

Answer (score 0):

The passage is saying $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}$ tends to $1$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.  (There's no integral sign in the display you have quoted.)  Ignoring the constant, this expression is the integrand for the second moment of the Cauchy distribution.  As a consequence and as you say, the integral over $(-\infty, \infty)$ diverges.